# Receiving same intent broadcast multiple times but only sending once

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an intent that gets sent under a certain condition.  The logs prove it is only sent ONCE, but the receiver is receiving it multiple times milliseconds apart.

```
10-01 10:09:59.201: I/System.out(13543): SENDER CHECKPOINT  
10-01 10:09:59.211: I/System.out(13543): RECEIVER CHECKPOINT 
10-01 10:09:59.291: I/System.out(13543): RECEIVER CHECKPOINT
```

I have confirmed that there is only ONE registration of the Broadcast Receiver and only ONE action filter used with the registered BR. It is only used in a single activity where a service running in another thread broadcasts the intent.  Again, the logs substantiate the ONE broadcast and multiple receipts.  What's more, the extras are null in the echo receipt.

How can this be?  Is it possible the OS is echoing it?

Code that sends the broadcast:

```
private void sendBroadcast(boolean status, String message, String action){
     System.out.println("SENDER CHECKPOINT");

     Intent intent = new Intent(action);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putBoolean("status", status);
     bundle.putString("message", message);
     intent.putExtras(bundle);
     sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

Code that receives the broadcast:

```
private class displayUpdate extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
            System.out.println("RECEIVER CHECKPOINT");


    };
}
```

Registration:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try {
        // just in case onResume is called w/o a pause  
        try{activity.unregisterReceiver(displayReceiver);}catch(Exception e){}

        filterRefreshUI = new IntentFilter(REFRESH_UI);
        activity.registerReceiver(displayReceiver, filterRefreshUI);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Unregistration:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try{unregisterReceiver(displayReceiver);}catch(Exception e){} 
}
```

REALLY IT'S THAT SIMPLE!  Yet the receiver fires TWICE!

In case you were wondering - Registration/Unregistration are handled in the onPause/onResume to prevent leaking memory if the App is killed by the OS.

Comment: Perhaps you have a bug in your code. Pity that we cannot help with that, since we cannot see your code from here.

Comment: Perhaps there is a bug, but the logs would show multiple broadcasts too.

Comment: Soo... I take it that means we won't be seeing any code? Well, good luck with that.

Comment: Okay, what exactly are you looking for?  I have a broadcast and receiver - what else would you want to see?  Logs don't lie - ONLY ONE BROADCAST BUT TWO RECEIPTS!!!

Comment: The most relevant parts would be anything that sends or receives the broadcast(maybe the manifest also). See this from our point of view. Debugging without code is hard, most times impossible. If you *have* the code and can't see what's wrong, what makes you think that someone *without* it will find the error? There's a reason one of the off-topic reasons says ["include valid code to reproduce the error"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Although this doesn't seem to be your situation, if you were sending the intent to a Service, and the Service was returning START_REDELIVER_INTENT and stopService was not called before the Service was terminated, then you would receive the intent again later.

Comment: Maybe you could provide code where you register receiver? Are you sure that you register it only once and only one instance?

Comment: Are you sure that you are unregistering the receiver? Your `catch` blocks don't do anything, not even log that it happened, so it doesn't look like you'd ever know.

Comment: If the BR truly was erring on unregistration, I would get memory leaks when the activity is killed.  Since I am not getting memory leaks, I am inclined to believe that the unregistration is working.  the handlers are there just in case to prevent a crash.

Comment: Furthermore, since it's a module level variable, I don't think it is possible to get multiple instances - but I am not certain on that point.